# Why does this program give this result?

Tags: python

Why does this code:

```
n = int(raw_input("How many rows? "))
for row in xrange(n):
    for col in xrange(row+1):
        print "*",
    print
```

Display this result (when n = 5)?

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
```

EDIT - I don't understand how step by step it gets this form. Does col mean the number of columns? Because it doesn't make sense as the number of columns is equal to the number of rows even though the input for columns is (rows+1).

Comment: What does it return? Please use code formatting (`{}` button) so your code is more readable!

Comment: take it a line at a time start with: what does `n=int(raw_input("...` do?

Comment: this smells like `homework` also

Comment: We were taught for loop with the range function but I don't know how to make sense out of this

Comment: edit your OP to show as much as you can in comments about what is happening ... if your just missing one small part to make the leap I'll be happy to help ... but you can tell school is back when you see all the questions that just want you to do their homework

Comment: Hmm... I agree with Joran. Wasn't thinking about homework when I posted an answer. OP, please show that you've made an attempt in the future.

Comment: It's actually a lesson for "for loops" and "xrange" and "range" functions. My homework is completely different. I need to first understand how these work!

Comment: ok well then thats fine.  learning is good ... asking for strait up answers is not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's go line-by-line and think like we're the computer.

- `n = int(raw_input("How many rows? "))` We get what the users inputs, convert it to an integer, and store the result in `n`.
- `for row in xrange(n):` We're looping over `xrange(n)`, which is more or less the same as `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` (although `xrange` doesn't store the full list at once, and so is more memory efficient). So now we know that whenever we see `row` in the future, we have to replace it with whichever one of those numbers we're on.
- `for col in xrange(row+1):` This line is similar to the last one; now `col` is one of the values in a list counting from `0` to the value stored in `row`. So if `row` is `2` on this iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will run 3 times. The first time `col` will equal `0`, the second `1`, and the third time it will equal `2`. (For each of those `col` values, `row` will stay `2`, since `row` only changes when the outer loop goes through an iteration.)
- `print "*",` This is where the `*`s actually get printed. The tricky bit here is the comma at the end of the line. A `print` statement without a comma just prints something and then moves to the next line. When you add the comma, it basically prints the line but adds a  space after the line instead of a new line (`\n`). So, since this line is called for each `col` value, it will print a `*` followed by a space on one line for each `col` value.
- `print` Notice that this is not inside the col loop. This statement just prints a newline. The idea here is to print a new line after each row has been printed so that the `*`s of the next rows are added to a new line, rather than to the previous line. If this `print` weren't here, all of the stars would be printed on a single line.

So, for each `row` value, this program prints `row+1` number of `*`s on one row.

**In response to question edit:**

I could see how `col` could be a confusing name. `col` is just the *current* column number of the `*` being printed. To see this more clearly, try replacing `print "*",` with `print col,`. You should get the following:

```
0
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
```

(Remember that `range(3)` produces `[0,1,2]`, while `range(3+1)` produces `[0,1,2,3]`.)

Answer (score 1):

your code tels it to do that.let's say n=5. then you jump into the `for` loop. The first time thorugh the var row is 0. therefore, when you start the second for loop for the columns, you write `xrange(row+1)`. Well, if row is 0, then row + 1 = 1. so It will display one star.and kicks out to the first for loop. ok, second iteration, the variable row becomes one. therefore, row + 1 = two, so when you enter the second for loop again, it will loop until hit hits two. then start over again, and the process repeats itself until you have 5 rows, each with enough columns to fulfill that row + 1 columns. Just follow the code one step at a time.